# Importing/Exporting Data in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have downloaded PostgreSQL a short while ago, I am trying to import a CSV into a table. However i keep getting this error.

"*ERROR:  extra data after last expected column*"

Me and my coworker have been going through the data testing various amounts of things, but cannot seem to get anything to be imported. I am stuck on where to go from now.

Comment: seems you have eg 10 fields in your headline, 11 in your data

Comment: In pgAdmin, do i have to manually enter the column names? I have tried importing without it and it does not work.

Comment: i use the copy command .... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#:~:text=COPY%20moves%20data%20between%20PostgreSQL,results%20of%20a%20SELECT%20query.

Comment: How does this work. I read the docs. Can i use copy to get all the data from a CSV into a table?

Comment: I have 300 columns inside a CSV. I need a way to implement these columns without having to do it manually